# Flutter url_launcher cannot open www. prefix

Tags: flutter, url

I want to know how to open this format URL using `url_launcer` in Flutter:

```
www.flutter.dev
flutter.dev
```

Because in my case the `url_launcer` only can open URL format like this:

```
https://www.flutter.dev
http://www.flutter.dev
https://flutter.dev
http://flutter.dev
```

And this is my error if I call the function URL to open `www.flutter.dev` or `flutter.dev`:

```
I/flutter (17563): Could not launch www.google.com/
I/flutter (17563): 
I/flutter (17563): #0      Navigation.launchURL (package:my_package/common/helpers/navigation.dart:39:7)
I/flutter (17563): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (17563): #1      CardAttachments.build.<anonymous closure> (package:my_package/widget/cards/attachments/card_attachments.dart:55:34)
I/flutter (17563): #2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
I/flutter (17563): #3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
I/flutter (17563): #4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
I/flutter (17563): #5      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:486:11)
I/flutter (17563): #6      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:264:5)
I/flutter (17563): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:236:7)
I/flutter (17563): #8      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:156:27)
I/flutter (17563): #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:222:20)
I/flutter (17563): #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:fl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check [supported schema url](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#supported-url-schemes) from this package.
You need to implement `http:` or `https:` at the beginning of the line to specify that this is a url.

You should use `canLaunch` for check the url before to launch it:

```dart
if (await canLaunch(url)){
   await launch(url);
} else {
   throw 'Could not launch ${url}';
}
```

You can add the http previously to variable.

```dart
String newUrl = 'http://' + url;
if (await canLaunch(newUrl)){
   await launch(newUrl);
} else {
  throw 'Could not launch ${newUrl}';
}
```

Check if it contains http

```dart
if( !url.substring(0, 5).contains('http') ) {
   url = 'http://' + url;
}
```

Comment: How if the user copy and the paste URL that has the default URL using `https` or `http`. So it will `http://http://www.google.com` . So it will not open the URL

Comment: You can control if the url you receive contains http, and if not add it. I have edited my answer adding an example at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void _launchURL(String url) async {
if(url.contains("http://")||url.contains("https://")){
  await canLaunch(url) ? await launch(url) : throw 'Could not launch Url';

}
else {
  String newUrl = "https://"+url;
  else {
  String newUrl = "https://"+url;
  await canLaunch(newUrl) ? await launch(newUrl) : throw 'Could not launch Url';

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Look at the function [parse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/parse.html) or [tryParse](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/tryParse.html)

And then you can write something like this

```
void launchURLBrowser(String url) async {
    Uri? uri = Uri.tryParse(url);
    String newUrl='';
    if(uri == null)throw 'Could not launch ${uri.toString()}';
    if(uri.scheme.isEmpty) newUrl = 'https://';
    newUrl += uri.toString();

    if (await canLaunch(newUrl)) {
      await launch(newUrl, forceSafariVC: false,
        forceWebView: false,);
    } else {
     throw 'Could not launch $newUrl';
    }
  }
```